# HTML5 Audio: Crop audio white space based on audio data

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-recording

My users are creating short audio recordings for a language learning site. 
I want a way to crop out the beginning and end from the clip so that there is not "white space" in the clip. Is there a way to find "white space" and clip it out based on the audio data? Here is some sample code from recorder.js plugin I'm using. I'm printing out e.inputBuffer in the console which gives me duration, length, num of channels and sample rate. None of this data seems to help determine white space.

```
this.context = source.context;
this.node = (this.context.createScriptProcessor || this.context.createJavaScriptNode).call(this.context, this.config.bufferLen, this.config.numChannels, this.config.numChannels);

    this.node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
    console.log(e.inputBuffer);//gives duration, length, num of channels, samplerate 
        if (!_this.recording) return;
        var buffer = [];
        for (var channel = 0; channel < _this.config.numChannels; channel++) {
            buffer.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel));
        }
        _this.worker.postMessage({
            command: 'record',
            buffer: buffer
        });
    };
```